# Finding a continuous distribution that maximizes differential entropy

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, information-theory, entropy

**Continuous distribution** (known mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$) - Maximum Entropy:
Given mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, what is the continuous distribution that maximizes differential entropy $h(X) = -\int_x f(x) \log f(x) dx$? I want to prove this.

I tried to calculate the KL-divergence between two distributions and came up with h(X) which is the second part of the equation. I am unable to solve this further. How to prove this

$KL[f\parallel g]=\int_f(x) \log \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}dx$

$= \int_{X} f(x) \log f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x - \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x) \log g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$

$= - \mathrm{h}[f(x)] - \int_{\mathcal{X}} f(x) \log g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$

Answer (score -1):

The differential entropy [is maximized by the normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy#Maximization_in_the_normal_distribution).

Comment: thanks for answer. But how to prove for special case of normal distribution (Continuous)?

Comment: What do mean, exactly, by "special case of normal distribution (Continuous)"?

Comment: what if i need to prove for continuous distribution not only normal,

Comment: @Alex : Prove what, exactly?